# How to combine 2 .exe to one by NSIS?

Tags: build, installation, nsis

I have 2 exe setup files. One of them is the C# application which I build with setup project and another one is the driver of camera that have to use with my application.

For example: myApp.msi + camDri.exe = new.exe

Anyone can guild me how to do that with NSIS?

Answer (score 1):

```
Name "MyApp"
Outfile "MyAppSetup.exe"
RequestexecutionLevel admin
InstallDir "$Programfiles\MyApp"

Page Directory
Page Instfiles

Section
Initpluginsdir

Setoutpath $pluginsdir
File "camDri.exe"
ExecWait '"$pluginsdir\camDri.exe" /silent' ;I don't know the correct silent switch
Delete "$pluginsdir\camDri.exe" 
File "myApp.msi"

Setoutpath $instdir
Exec '"msiExec" /q /i "$pluginsdir\myApp.msi" TargetDir = "$INSTDIR"' 

SectionEnd
```

This is a very basic example, you should look at the examples that ship with NSIS for details about uninstalling and creating start menu shortcuts etc...